# How to redirect to a page after successful login and implement tokens within the templates in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

**I am completely new to using JWT authentication in Django and don't know how to implement tokens within each template of my application. I am using JWT (JSON Web Tokens) instead of sessions.**

**Scenario:**

I have a login form that uses AJAX where after clicking the submit button, it points to my API and takes the credentials of a registered user. If authenticated, I intend to use JWT authentication and access the dashboard page, and include those tokens within the page (instead of using sessions). However, I am not redirecting to the specified URL after logging in. Furthermore, I have used **Simple-JWT** in order to generate tokens but don't know how to include them in my template (AJAX call) in order to access an API. I have tried the following:

**views.py:**

```
I have created a login form that doesnt access the values. 
Instead, I have used AJAX in my template in order to point it towards the LoginAPI below:

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            pass #not doing anything here since all I need is a form for logging in.
    else:
        login_form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, "users/login.html", {"login_form" : login_form})

#Login API that gets called after clicking the form submit button.
class LoginAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format = None):
        username = request.data['username'] 
        password = request.data['password'] 

        new_user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if new_user is not None:
            url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/token/' #need to pass in the credentials in order to access the JWT tokens.
            values = {
                'username' : username,
                'password' : password
            }
            r = requests.post(url, data = values) 
            token_data = r.json() 
            return Response(token_data) #should return the JSON tokens to AJAX in success function.
        else:
            return Response({"status" : "Denied."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField()
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from users import views as users_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users.views import LoginAPI
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login_api/', LoginAPI.as_view(), name = 'login_api'),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('login/', user_views.login, name = 'login'),
]
```

**login.html:**

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script src='{% static "users/js/main.js" %}'></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ login_form|crispy }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" id='login'> Login </button>
            </div>
         </form>
     </div>

 {% endblock content %}
```

**main.js (the file that contains the AJAX function):**

```
$('#login').click(function () {
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();    
$.ajax({
cache: false,
method: 'POST',  
url: "/login_api/", #After click, the URL should point towards the LoginAPI in views.py
data: {username:username, password: password},
datatype: 'json',
success: function(data) {  
    console.log(data.access);
    localStorage.setItem('access', data.access);
    window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/punch_funcs';  #the template I wish to go to after successful logging in.

},
```

When testing the login form, I found out that I am being redirected to my template 'punch_funcs'. But the URL is the same as my login page which means that whenever I refresh the page, I am taken back to my login template:

```
'http://localhost:8000/login' this should be 'http://localhost:8000/punch_funcs' instead.
```

Also, the tokens have been generated successfully, but how can I place this within my 'punch_funcs' template in order to access several APIs (not listed in the code above)?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.